# Options for implementing call masking in Twilio C#

Tags: c#, twilio

As a bit of background for my issue, I am creating an "on-call" system which allows a user to call into the system for an issue and get their call forwarded to the person on call who can help. I have [implemented this in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp). Problem I am trying to fix now is to someway identify that the call came from the Twilio system. I don't want to add a verify number as the caller id because then if the on call person misses the call, they do not have the correct number to call back. Also I am not using the Twilio Client. Is there any way to add maybe an asterisk, or something to outbound callerid number from Twilio? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:
In Twilio it is, as of August 2016, not possible to change the caller id to anything other than a twilio number for anyone who ever looks at this. [Here is the link](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180148-Displaying-a-business-name-or-custom-text-as-Caller-ID)